# REST Web Service JSONObject Data Binding Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I am attempting to create client pojo class for below samplejson response from REST webservices using jackson data binding.

```
"txn": {
    "TXN_DATE": {
      "=": "20170428"
    },
    "TXN_AMT": {
      "=": "2000.00"
    }
    "TXN_TYPE": {
      "=": "SB"
    }
}
```

It is kind of object inside object. so i created pojo property as

```
private Map<String, org.json.JSONObject> test2 = null;
```

if i use org.json.JSONObject then i get below exception is occuring :

> Could not write content: No serializer found for class
>   org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create
>   BeanSerializer

else if i use **org.json.simple.JSONObject or net.sf.json.JSONObject** then no exception is occuring and json to pojo is converting successful.

My doubt is why org.json.JSONObject is not supporting and which json package should i use for this scenario.
Also can i use `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` over JSONObject. which one is better.
Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use org.json.JSONObject instead of putting it inside a map.

```
JSONObject jObject =  null;
jObject = new JSONObject(String you want to parse);
JSONObject jObject2 =jObject.getJSONObject("txn");
JSONObject jobject3 = jObject2.getJSONObject("TXN_DATE");
String jobject4 =  jobject3.getString("=");
```

jobject4 will give 20170428

Comment: JSONObject jobject3 = jObject2.jObject2("TXN_DATE"); is it right.